# Monitor goes to sleep in the middle of installation

Tags: 11.04

I installed Ubuntu on my laptop and it was successful. I liked it so much that I wanted to install it on my desktop.

When I try to install onto the desktop the monitor goes to sleep when Ubuntu is halfway installed.

I think the graphics cards is an issue, but I don't know. I have a Nvidia GeForce 9600 Gs graphics card.

I've tried the following but these have not worked -  the monitor always goes to sleep:

- two different monitors via VGA.
- dual boot with wubi
- installing via the live CD
- installed a brand new hard drive just for Ubuntu,
- Installing via the alternate CD
- Tried Nomodeset
- Tried Noapic
- I found the solution to my problem graphic card was over heating. Is fix now and ubuntu is up and running.Thank you guys for the help!!!!!

Comment: Have you tried turning powersaving off in BIOS? I have no idea if it is the issue but imo it's worth a shot.

Comment: Did you try moving the mouse or pressing the space bar?  :p

Comment: Well is not a problem with the CPU going to sleep just the monitor. I tried moving the mouse and space bar.lol. I run a test for my motherboard and graphics card in windows and it says they are working fine, but I don't know. Today I was watching a movie in windows and all of a sudden the monitor went to sleep and the dvd stop spinning, but the cpu is still on an running not at sleep. That's what happens when I'm try to install ubuntu.

Comment: Please add your solution as an answer - otherwise your question will not be answered in the system.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

1. Before you boot the live cd (or the live usb) choose `nomodeset`.
2. You also can try others settings at boot like `acpi=off` and `noapic`
3. [WelshBluebird](http://www.neowin.net/forum/user/122135-welshbluebird/) [has reported the same problem](http://www.neowin.net/forum/topic/616183-ubuntu-monitor-turning-off-during-boot/) if he keeps his wireless card attached.

Reference: [1](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1516317).

Comment: SO i CLICK nomodeset and then what do I do. I try hitting nomodeset and then install ubuntu, but the monitor went to sleep.

Comment: You know I think it might be something wrong with graphics card because when I enter my computer bios the monitor would go to sleep. I was having the same problem with windows where my monitor would randomly go to sleep. I updated the drivers for windows and it stop doing that. I try nomedeset and monitor goes to sleep.

Comment: I've edited the answer with more alternatives.

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution to my own problem. The problem was that my graphics card was over heating during the installation. I took out the graphics card cleaned it and then installed a new fan and now it is working fine. I got to install Ubuntu 11.04 64bit.

Thanks everyone for the help.

Answer (score 0):

If the monitor goes to sleep when you are in the BIOS screen (before any OS is loaded), then it's a hardware or (more strange) a BIOS issue.

Try to update your computer BIOS as the last resort. I fear that the most likely cause is a hardware problem (either monitor or video card related).

Comment: yeah most likely is the video card because it happens in either one of my monitors, and I just bought one of them not even a year ago. What I don't get is that the monitor goes to sleep only when I'm installing ubuntu. When I run windows is all fine.

Comment: The fun thing is that it sleeps while in BIOS. Maybe the BIOS, at boot time is setting something wrong in the video card (likely in power saving settings). It could be possible that windows drivers reverse it, but Ubuntu drivers don't. This could explain why it sleeps when it's controlled by the BIOS or Ubuntu but not Windows. This is also I ask you to update the BIOS. This is just a highly speculative idea, more likely to be wrong than right, but it's worth trying.